# Is TubeSat legit?

Tags: launch, cubesat

I've been looking into a personal satellite. The CubeSat seems interesting but is upwards of 10k for a satellite and extra for the launch. Not something in my price range.

I found TubeSat by [Interorbital](http://www.interorbital.com/). They have a $8,000 kit that includes the launch. But the website looks like it's from the 80s with some HTML errors thrown in. Besides the website and a few articles mentioning it I haven't found much information on Interorbital.

Is Interorbital legit? Do they really do launches?

Comment: Sounds like they had a flight to 10K feet in 2014 but that's it.  Your call. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interorbital_Systems

Comment: It looks like they are legitimately trying, but it doesn't sound like they are very close.

Comment: Have you tried contacting them ?

Answer (score 5):

They seem to be a paper launch company, but they haven't made any work towards actually launching a rocket. I wouldn't count on them launching you to space anytime soon. See [Gunter's Space Page on the Neptune rocket](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/neptune.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Interorbital Systems is very much alive and continues to offer its TubeSat and CubeSat Kit-and-Launch packages. The company is completing ground testing of its gimbal and guidance system and is preparing for a guided test flight this summer (2016). The current launch manifest includes 128 orbital payloads (see www.interorbital.com), slated to begin launches in early 2017, after completion of the flight test program and licensing. Commercial suborbital services began in 2014, launching and recovering four payloads; summer 2016 launch will carry 11 small sat payloads for testing before their 2017-2018 scheduled orbital launches. If you would like information about our services, please contact me at ios@interorbital.com. ~ Randa Milliron, CEO/CoFounder, Interorbital Systems.

Comment: I believe you should add this as a comment. This answer is not in SE standarts it will prob get negged and possibly deleted.

Comment: @VolkanOzcan i just looked into that myself. The answer genuinely answers the question, and the question is legit. It emphasizes the positive, to be sure, but is factual and sticks to the matter at hand. The asker did after all say they were considering business with them. Odd case, to be sure...

Comment: @Interorbital How'd the guided test flight in summer 2016 go?