# Launch options for a hobbyist cubesat builder who's not rich?

Tags: launch, low-earth-orbit, commercial, reliability

For a while now I've been waning to launch a satellite into space, making the satellite should be simple enough, I have some experience with Arduino and coding in general. but what I don't have is any way to launch anything into space.

I am looking for something similar to a tubesat (e.g. [Tancredo-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tancredo-1))

I am not rich, what are my launch options?

Comment: At first you need a lot of money. Launching something into space is not cheap at all. Not only the launcher should be reliable but also the payload. You need to test your satellite intensively under simulated space conditions.

Comment: If you can design the satellite to CubeSat specifications and it can support one of [NASA's strategic objectives](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/6-nasa_2018_strategic_plan_mar2018_tagged.pdf), you may be eligible for NASA's [CubeSat Launch Initiative](https://www.nasa.gov/content/about-cubesat-launch-initiative). Does that sound like something that would work for you?

Comment: something like a cube sat is what I am looking to launch, but when ive looked at prices for launching cube sats they are monumental, a price i cant afford right now, ive also heard they are in an orbit that lasts a very short period which is something i do not want.

Comment: @Topcode It's hard to make further recommendations without knowing your objectives.

Comment: If you think "making the satellite should be simple enough" you might know too few about the problems in making reliable space qualified hardware.

Comment: @Uwe This was my thought--don't need it's orbit to last longer if the satellite quits working anyway.

Comment: You want a cubesat with uplink and downlink capability to exchange data and commands? Transceivers from this [page](https://www.cubesatshop.com/product-category/communication-systems/) are sold for some k€. But you need to rent or own some ground station capacity too.

Comment: There's a vote to close your question because answers may be "primarily opinion based" so I've adjusted the wording to avoid that. How does it look? Also, slightly related: [Is TubeSat legit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16871/12102)

Comment: @uhoh Unfortunately you removed the OP's request specifically for a commercial launch provider. They still have not made their objectives clear and a commercial launch provider may be key to that. They shyed away from my NASA-option answer without directly saying no.

Comment: @called2voyage I see what you mean, your discussion with the user was on-going and I shouldn't have jumped in with an edit to the question. I should have read comments more carefully. Should I roll back?

Comment: @uhoh I say leave it and let the OP edit if they choose to.